SCIM / Entra ID Provisioning: How to remove user attributes in the target system?
GET Users/{Id} returns the following json:
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
  ],
  "id": "16960d38-728d-4865-925c-165caf50708d",
  "externalId": "16960d38-728d-4865-925c-165caf50708d",
  "userName": "foo@example.com",
  "name": {
    "givenName": "",
    "familyName": "Foo"
  },
  "active": true
}

When I change the value of the "familyName" or "givenName" attribute in MS Entra, Entra makes a PATCH request with the following body:
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "op": "Add",
      "path": "name.givenName",
      "value": "Bar"
    },
    {
      "op": "Replace",
      "path": "name.familyName",
      "value": "Foo2"
    }
  ]
}

But when I delete the "familyName" or "givenName" attribute in Entra, Entra does NOT send a "Remove" "op".
Why is that? And how can I remove the attribute in my target system then?
Thank you in advance!

Entra ID doesn't send a "Remove" operation for deleted attributes; it simply omits them from the request. To remove attributes in the target system, configure it to treat missing attributes as deletions or implement custom logic to handle absent values.

Hi Rukmini. Sorry, I don't get it. Entra only PATCHes me the changed attributes. So no matter if I delete one attribute or keep it as it is, it never sends me this attribute in the PATCH request (When doing on-demand provisioning, Entra says "SkipReason
RedundantExport"). It only sends a PATCH when one attribute is created or edited. So when one attribute is deleted my endpoint is never called! My attribute is also configured as "Apply this mapping: Always" but its never send if not changed...

AFAIK Entra ID does not send a "Remove" operation for deleted attributes; it simply omits them. To handle this, configure your target system to treat missing attributes as deletions or implement custom logic to detect and process absent values.

Hi Rukmini. Yes, you said that before. But since there is no difference whether an attribute value is deleted or an attribute value left unchanged how should I handle this in my app, if I can not differ?

To handle this in your app, you can track the last known state of the attributes. If an attribute is missing in the current request, treat it as deleted, or flag it for removal based on your business logic. This allows you to differentiate between unchanged and deleted attributes.

"Treat missing attributes as.." requires the SCIM client (Entra) to include all attributes in each update request, which is what you'd see in a PUT update request. Entra uses PATCH, which generally only includes the changed attributes. As a result, it isn't possible to build logic in the SCIM server for attribute values being missing in update requests.

Entra's app provisioning service doesn't support removing values from attributes at this time.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/known-issues?pivots=app-provisioning#null-attribute-cant-be-provisioned

I just tried setting the value in Entra to " " (one whitespace character) instead of "" and this works for string fields. :P At least a little workaround.
